# Array subset using hashing

Tags: arrays, hash, hashtable, subset

To check if arr2 is subset.
Input: `arr1[] = {11, 1, 13, 21, 3, 7}, arr2[] = {11, 3, 7, 1}`
Output: `arr2[]` is a subset of `arr1[]`

If we use linear probing.
Hashtable will look like:
`{0=7, 1=1, 2=13, 3=21, 4=3, 5=11}` where first item is index(hashed code) second is value
If you see for element 7. Hash code is `7%6=1`. So from 1 it has to traverse complete hashtable by checking every bucket. Here Time Complexity is O(n)

Later on we will be searching all elements in `arr2` with hashtable.

So overall time complexity will be Len(arr2)*O(n).

What is the benefit of hashing then?

Answer (score 0):

The best-case complexity of search operation in hash table is not O(n), but O(1). So in best case you will get complexity Len(arr2) * O(1) => Len(arr2), and we can treat it as O(1).
On the other hand, the worst-case complexity is really O(n).
So, you should look at amortized cost of entire algorithm, that will be lower, than O(n)

Comment: How can you say overall complexity as O(1). Len(arr2) will be N. It has to traverse complete array .

Comment: I know the stuff that you have mentioned. But do a dry run for this case. 
you will it has to traverse complete hashtable and come back to 0 . So O(n) is complexity.
So,overall complexity : O(M*N)

Comment: Ok, we can represent Len(1) as n and Len(2) as m, than in best-case overall complexity will be O(m), in best case it will be O(mn), but amortized complexity will be less then O(mn). It case, if you will not use hashtable, it will be O(mn)

Comment: @SachitMurarka usually, any standalone case is not representative for algorithm, you should check it with as much possible edge-cases as possible

Comment: Yes. That's true. Our complexity will lie between 1 and mn if we use hashtable

Comment: What is amortized cost?

Comment: @SachitMurarka Amortized cost (complexity) is the total expense per operation, evaluated over a sequence of operations. In fact, in our case it's the average complexity of operations evaluated for all possible arrays 1 and 2.